# Best way to log java.net.URL results

Tags: java, logging, inputstream

I have a library function as follows:

```
public static InputStream getResource(String url) throws MalformedURLException,
    IOException {
    return new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
}
```

What would be the best way to add logging to this method to record the actual url response. Will I have to read the InputStream and then reset it?

(You can assume that I just want to print the results to the console for the sake of this example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might copy the contents of the stream to a byte array, using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, log the content of the byte array, and then return a `ByteArrayInputStream` constructed from the byte array. This puts the whole contents in memory, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use a logger library and requests are small, then you could read whole InputStream into memory (e.g. into ByteArrayOutputStream), then log it, then construct ByteArrayInputStream as the method result.

If requests are big, you should dump it somewhere into a file or into a database blob. You could subclass the `FilterInputStream` and dump the data flow.

You cannot reset http stream in most cases.